# Is there a way to customize the default AWSAuthUI sign in screen when using AWS Cognito with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm looking to customize the style of the AWSAuthUI sign in screen that is provided when using AWS Cognito user pools with a iOS application written in Swift. Things that I would like to do are remove the default logo, change the text in an input box and remove a field from the sign up interface. If anybody has a link to some thorough documentation or a code example that would be excellent. I'm not afraid of digging through documentation myself but I can't seem to find anything that goes into much detail. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at this issue too but the default options are

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/authentication

The Code example from the docs

```
AWSMobileClient.default()
    .showSignIn(navigationController: self.navigationController!,
                     signInUIOptions: SignInUIOptions(
                           canCancel: false,
                           logoImage: UIImage(named: "MyCustomLogo"),
                            backgroundColor: UIColor.black)) { (result, err) in
                            //handle results and errors               
}
```

I have found an example for Android but I suspect its not current: https://pragmaapps.com/aws-cognito-custom-signin-ui/

The docs have examples of using the AWSMobileClient to requests to the API:
https://docs.amplify.aws/sdk/auth/working-with-api/q/platform/ios#confirm-signin-mfa

Which I would take is the other option to build a custom UI to interact with the User Pool.